# How do I create a second close button on my modal (in addition to the top left x)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to add another "Cancel" button on the bottom of the modal in addition to the span option to close the modal. Not sure where to go from here please advise on some options. Thanks

```
<!-- The Offer Modal-->
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="makeOfferBtn">Make an Offer</button>
<!-- The Offer Modal content -->
<div id="myOfferModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myOfferModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("makeOfferBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty example that will work with any number of buttons that has the `.close` class defined:

```
// Selecting all nodes that are `.close`
var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

// Iterating over on all of them and 
// attaching handlers for the 'click' event. 
for (var i = 0, max = closeBtns.length; i < max; i++) {
    var close = closeBtns[i];
    close.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

However, I would recommend to restructure your code a bit in order to not to use so many global variables.